# Mysql Select 1 column AS

Tags: mysql

I am wanting to select 1 column from my select statement as but then leave the rest as is so:

```
SELECT tbl_user.reference AS "reference", * FROM tbl_user JOIN tbl_details ON.....
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use double quotes like that to create a column alias. You can SELECT a column twice (or more) in your `SELECT` list.

Try something like this, where you can give each "reference" column its own alias:

```
 SELECT u.reference AS UserReference,
        d.reference as DetailsReference,
        u.id, /*etc etc*/
 FROM   tbl_user AS U
 JOIN   tblDetails AS D ON ....
```

You mention in the comments that you want all columns from each table, while being able to distinguish between the reference columns(likely named the same in both tables).  Suggest [NOT using `SELECT *`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select), as it's an anti-pattern. It's most beneficial to specify your column list in your SELECT statement, and do your query engine a favour of not having to look up the list of columns on each table.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want one column, this will work:

```
SELECT SELECT tbl_user.username AS "username" FROM tbl_user JOIN tbl_details on tbl_user.key LIKE tbl_details.key
```

What do you mean by "but then leave the rest as is "?

Comment: I just edited the question to be more realistic and make more sense. I need all columns from both tables but both tables have a column reference which has different values and the one displayed in my output is the wrong one. I mean leave rest as is as I dont want to be writing tbl_user.name, tbl_details.id etc for all columns as there are a lot of columns in each table